# Resetting lifeline activations at beginning of each alternative

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Assuming that sequence-diagram alternatives should be somewhat interchangeable, how does one deal with an alternative leaving lifelines with a different number of (possibly nested) activations than it encountered at the beginning? For example, here are sequence diagrams for a "ready" case, a "not-ready" case, and a failed attempt to combine those cases in a single sequence diagram using "alt". (Sorry about the diagrams--I couldn't figure out how to top align them.)

[image: ready case][image: not-ready case][image: combined cases]

Looking at the last, "combined cases" diagram, notice that the first, "ready case" alternative is presented with one activation each of A and B and none for C. However, because this alternative creates new activations for B and C, the second, "not-ready case" alternative is presented with a different set of activations. I could add various messages at the end of "ready case" to arbitrarilly leave it with the same activations it originally encountered, but surely there is a better way, or am I missing something, e.g., I'm using alt incorrectly?

BTW, I generated these diagrams with [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com).

Comment: What causes the difference between ready/not ready?

Comment: Unknown environmental influences. :-) But that's immaterial to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sequence diagrams in this way but be careful: When a lifeline is active while entering the alt fragment it should be active on leaving the fragment to. And when it is not active no entering then it shouldn't be on leaving.

In your `combined cases` diagram is a problem with that regarding the lifeline of `C`. I suggest that every other action regarding `C` that you planned maybe for it after the fragment should be part of the `[ready case]`. Otherwise the diagram gets inconsistent from my perspective.

Comment: You've basically just restated the problem. And there is also an activations problem with B, not just C. I was hoping to focus on an isolated interaction, but UML sequence diagrams are apparently unable to represent this. Including activity following the fragment would be immaterial and distracting for my purposes. I'll have to leave these as two, separate diagrams.

Comment: Sorry, I would love to help you, but I still don't really understand your problem exactly. Can you give the big picture of your question?

Comment: I think I answered my own question, below. What do you think? Basically, using a UML Sequence Diagram, an alternative must end with the same set of activations with which it started. This is an arbitrary limitation of the notation and is not an inherent property of alternatives in general.

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't see it. I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use two separate SDs named `ready case` and `not-ready case`. You should not try to implement graphical programming with SDs. If you can transport a message with your diagrams in an easy way then take that road. As so often Occam applies.

Comment: These are simplified versions of my real diagrams. The pre-alt activity is more complex, and I would rather not duplicate it in multiple diagrams. I was just wondering how one _would_ represent them as a single diagram--an academic exercise.

Comment: There is is no duplication. When you put both into one diagram you have an additional fragment. Else you have two diagrams. Even. However, if you want to stuff both in a single diagram the `alt` fragment is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it some more and came to this conclusion. I won't consider marking this as the best answer until others have had a chance to respond.

Two axioms of alternative fragments are 1. all alternatives are presented with the same set of activations, α, upon entry and 2. all alternatives end with the same set of activations, β. The problem with UML Sequence Diagram notation, IMO, is that it has a separate, non-axiomatic requirement that each alternative ends with the same set of activations with which it was presented, or α = β.

Comment: Yesterday I thought about whether it would be a good idea, to send the kill message diagonal from the fragment crossing the end of the fragment via a time constraint message. What do you think?